# Override default soft keyboard

Tags: android, overriding, android-softkeyboard

In my app, the user is required to input car license plates (It's a private app for parking guards). However, the default Android keyboard is extremely inefficient to do that. My client has asked me to override the default keyboard to make it easier.

I've been told this is a dangerous approach, but this is a private app that only 3 people will use so security risks aren't that important.

I only need to override it in one EditText, so alternative methods are also welcome.

How can I override the default keyboard layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My client has asked me to override the default keyboard to make it easier.

That is not possible.

> I've been told this is a dangerous approach

It's an impossible approach.

> I only need to override it in one EditText, so alternative methods are also welcome.

Don't use an `EditText`. Use your own set of `Button` widgets and a `TextView`.

> How can I override the default keyboard layout?

You can't. You are welcome to write your own input method editor (a.k.a., soft keyboard). However, the *user* has to decide to use it -- you cannot force it upon them. That may be sufficient for your scenario.

Comment: How can I show that set of Button widgets? I need it to look exactly as if the soft keyboard came up.

Comment: @santirivera92: "How can I show that set of Button widgets?" -- the same way you do the rest of your UI. "I need it to look exactly as if the soft keyboard came up" -- that will not be especially easy, though you can use animations to show some sort of container that holds your `Button` widgets, sliding it up from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Sigh, this is kind of dissapointing and will upset my client. Whatever, thank you very much.